# Android how to select wifi network interface to send udp packet

Tags: android, networking, wifi, network-interface, 3g-network

I am working on Android project that will send UDP packets to another device through this device Access Point, this access point doesn't have internet connect.

The problem here is that when the user turns on 3G internet data, the os send the packet over 3G as a default network interface because the other network has no internet (the internet is not reachable).

I tried to turn off 3G internet Data programmatically, but it fails on Android 6+

Thanks

Comment: Add a broadcast to observe networking state, maybe you cannot change network by code.

Comment: did you resolve it?